# I want to delete multiple data on datagridview using checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (bool.Parse(item.Cells[0].Value.ToString()))
        {
                MessageBox.Show("Selected Rows  :  " + item.Cells[0].RowIndex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add more information to your post, not just provide a poorly written title with even more poorly formatted code.

Answer (score 0):

**Try below code**

```
    protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in gvDetails.Rows)
        {
            //Finiding checkbox control in gridview for particular row using below syntax
            CheckBox chkdelete = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("chkSelect");
            //Condition to check checkbox selected or not
            if (chkdelete.Checked)
            {
                //Getting UserId of particular row using datakey value
                int usrid = Convert.ToInt32(gvDetails.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value);
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SureshDasari;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=MySampleDB"))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from UserDetails where UserId=" + usrid, con);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        BindUserDetails();
    }
```

If you want to know more see below link

http://tinyurl.com/jgw33xs

Comment: Op is asking about DataGridview not Gridview.means its a Windows Forms

Answer (score 0):

When the button3 is clicked the following event handler is executed. It first gets the checked (selected) rows from the DataGridView using LINQ query and then displays a confirmation Message Box.

If the User clicks Yes button then a loop is executed over the selected (checked) rows and one by one records are deleted from the database table using the Id field.

**Note:** Database query taken here is to make OP understand how he can achieve it as OP didnt mention anything in his post , this will be a way to explain in a better way

```
   private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<DataGridViewRow> selectedRows = (from row in dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                                                where Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["checkBoxColumn"].Value) == true
                                                select row).ToList();
        if (MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Do you want to delete {0} rows?", selectedRows.Count), "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in selectedRows)
            {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Customers WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId", con))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerId", row.Cells["CustomerId"].Value);
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

            this.BindGrid();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @cFrozenDeath just an example , i cant give , even he gives his database cant use it and give a solution, only way i want to help is how he can execute it and this something a working example , so that OP can implement the same , with much less data from OP , this is the only way (taking example from my own working code) and explain him how to achieve it. correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it worked for me:

```
            int j = 0;
            int countRows = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1.Rows[i]
                                      .Cells[0].Value) == true)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
                }

                i = i - 1;
                j = j + 1;

                if (j == countRows)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score -2):

When you removed one row ,first is removed the row, the new values of size of row of datagrid is total minus one, for that reason I am using i --. And why use in a conditional "if (i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count -1)" because only is necessary subtract when rows[i] is 1 not when is 0.

You can use try catch instead of conditional.

Good luck!

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count -1; i++)
        {
            if ((bool)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value == true)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(dataGridView1.Rows[i]);
                if (i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count -1)
                {
                    i--;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add a description of why you think this is the answer and explain your code.

Comment: You should loop backwards instead to avoid missing deletion of consecutive selected rows - i.e. loop from last row to first row, i--.

Comment: Pradeep Kumar, Yes, that's possible but your going to have a value +1 of datGridView1.Rows.Count that is inaccesible, also can use try catch to solve the problem. Test it please!.